# Query to get intersect

Tags: sql, database

I am solving some problems about SPJ database.

```
S(SNUM, SNAME) [supplier]
P(PNUM, PNAME) [part]
J(JNUM, JNAME) [project]
SPJ(SNUM, PNUM, JNUM, Q)
```

The query is: Get pairs of projects that have at least 100 parts in common.
I have written a code for it so far:

```
SELECT X.JNUM, Y.JNUM FROM SPJ AS X, SPJ AS Y
    WHERE 100 <= (SELECT COUNT(PNUM) FROM (SELECT PNUM FROM SPJ WHERE SPJ.JN=X.JN 
                                            INTERSECT
                                           SELECT PNUM FROM SPJ WHERE SPJ.JN=Y.JN));
```

I think my solution is correct. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please tag with your RDBMS, e.g. `Sql-Server`, `Oracle`, etc.

Comment: Well your solution is not wrong, but you would not use a cartesian product on all records of *spj* when you only want all jnum pairs. Each jnum can have may records in spj, so you have the same combinations again and again and your result would show many duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply get all same-part combinations, then see how many matches you get per project pair:

```
select spj1.jnum as jnum1, spj2.jnum as jnum2 
from spj spj1
join spj spj2 on spj1.pnum = spj2.pnum and spj1.jnum < spj2.jnum
group by spj1.jnum, spj2.jnum
having count(distinct spj1.pnum) >= 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

- The derived table needs an alias
- Since you are doing the cartesian product you'll want to exclude joins to the same `SPJ`, and presumably you don't want the diagonals mirroring eachother, i.e. you won't need two pairs returned for `(SPJ1, SPJ2)` and `(SPJ2, SPJ1)`:

```
SELECT X.JNUM, Y.JNUM FROM SPJ AS X, SPJ AS Y
WHERE 100 <= (SELECT COUNT(PNUM) 
                 FROM (SELECT PNUM FROM SPJ WHERE SPJ.JN=X.JN 
                         INTERSECT
                       SELECT PNUM FROM SPJ WHERE SPJ.JN=Y.JN) as AnAlias)
     AND X.PK > Y.PK; -- Avoid duplicates and self false positives
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other methods to do so? Maybe a shorter one or faster?